# Winapi and half fadeout window

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to fade out window using winapi in c++. I want to make the effect like windows when they are not responsible. They are become then whole gray and half transparent. I'm trying to do it using

```
AnimateWindow(hwnd, 1000, AW_BLEND | AW_HIDE);
```

but this make the window hide becouse of paramether AW_HIDE and I want to fade out for example only for 70%. Is there any way to do it using animate window or maybe I can do it another way?

Comment: These are two different kinds of fading (to transparent and to white, respectively), and for different purpouses.

Comment: I'm interested in fading to thite I thing

Comment: SetLayeredWindowAttributes

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [UpdateLayeredWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This code changes the opacity of window, when `WM_LBUTTONUP` event occur.
If you want to animate for 'fade out' effect, using  **Timer** can be an effective method.
In `WM_TIMER` handler, change the alpha_value which is third parameter of `::SetLayeredWindowAttributes()`.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    LONG extend_style;
    BYTE alpha_value;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        ...
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:

        extend_style = ::GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE );
        ::SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extend_style | WS_EX_LAYERED );

        //0 ~ 255(Transparent Range, 0 is completely transparent)       
        alpha_value = 100; 

        ::SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, alpha_value, LWA_ALPHA);

        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
         ...
         break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this will help you a little.